# Send emails to every user matching criteria

Tags: php

I have updated my code due to the following suggestions in the comments. The issue now is I get an error. Here's the new code:

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$idspam = "1";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE ID = '$idspam'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $companyname = $row['CompanyName'];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $Agent = $row['username'];
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $Agentmail = $row['mail'];
    $checkstat = "New customer";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = '$checkstat' AND Agent = '$Agent'");
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach($rows as $row)
        {
        $LastName = $row['LastName'];
        if (empty($row['ProductPriceUSD'])) {
            $ProductPriceEUR = $row['ProductPriceEUR'];
            $symbol = "&#8364;";
            $Productprice = ($ProductPriceEUR . $symbol);
        }
        if (empty($row['ProductPriceEUR'])) {
            $ProductPriceUSD = $row['ProductPriceUSD'];
            $symbol = "$";
            $Productprice = ($symbol . $ProductPriceUSD);
        }
        $CustomerPriceRAW = $row['CustomerPrice'];
        $eur = "&#8364;";
        $email = $row['Email']; 
        $a = mt_rand(100000,999999);
        $MD5Pass = md5($LastName . $a);
        $type = "Initial";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE AddedBy = '$Agent' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $content = $row['Content'];
            $subject = $row['Subject'];
        }
        $Newstatus = "Contacted";
        $Newline = "<br>";
        $replaceWord = array(

        "[name]" => $row['FirstName'],
        "[lastname]" => $row['LastName'],
        "[product]" => $row['ProductName'],
        "[username]" => $row['CustomerUser'],
        "[agent]" => $row['Agent'],
        "[productssold]" => $row['ProductsSold'],
        "[customerprice]" => ($CustomerPriceRAW . $eur),
        "[password]" => ($LastName . $a),
        "[productprice]" => $Productprice,
        "[newline]" => $Newline,
        );
        ob_start();
        include("./email/mailtemplate.php");
        $sendmsg = ob_get_clean();
        $message = $sendmsg;
        $body = strtr($content, $replaceWord);
        $headers = "From:".$companyname." ".$Agentmail."\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $contactdate = date("Y-m-d");
        $sevendays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"));
        $todo = "Followup";
        mysql_query("UPDATE data SET CustomerPass = '$MD5Pass', Status = '$Newstatus', Contacted = '$contactdate', SevenDays = '$sevendays', ToDo = '$todo'");
        mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
}

?>
```

And here is the error I get

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/user/public_html/cronmailinitial.php on line 22
```

Why? I want to pick all my employees (first foreach) and contact each of their clients. So an example is:
For Agent "John"
Pick all customers added by "John"
For each of them select a different E-mail template
Send

That's what it's suppose to do anyways. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. this API is deprecated
2. change all the

   while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))

to something more like

```
$rows = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
foreach( $rows as $row )
{
  .. do something with $row....
}
```

Comment: Heya, I know it is but it's too late to change it now, it will be revamped in an update.
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE Status = '$checkstat'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))`

is where I'd change `while` to `foreach` like you said, and than migrate the E-mail template selection code from the beginning to that?

Comment: put the mysql_fetch_array on it's own line. don't loop it. use the result of this call to loop the values. It returns an array.

Comment: You're using the same var in nested loops. Use something different for one of them. That and your first loop is still using the invalid syntax.

Comment: If you mean the one grabbing company name, that's because I need the company name to be the same for all loops? Thanks

Comment: No - the next two calls to 'foreach( $rows as $row )...' - then you also reset the value of $rows

Comment: Bah.. I switched it to while because for was returning random stuff no matter what I did.. Now it won't send E-mails, it does everything except that. I'll dive into this and hopefully post a solution soon